# How can I stack 2 span6 classes on top of each other in my Joomla Template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am looking to create a page in my Joomla Template where I will have 2 columns that will take up 50% of the page showing an image and text underneath. My code is shown below:

```
<div id="services" class="span12">
<div id="services-img-new" class="span6"></div>
<div id="services-img-new" class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div id="services" class="span12">
<div id="services-text" class="span6">
<h4>Heading 1</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
<div id="services-text" class="span6">
<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that if the screen size is reduced then this doesnt show the correct text under the right image and from my code i can see this is obviously because i have grouped the 2 images together and the text together.

How am i able to group the image and text together as one?

If somebody could please advise, would really appreciate it.

Btw I am currently using Joomla 3.5.1 and Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 hence not using the col classes as it is in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand correctly your looking for something like this:

```
<div id="services" class="span6">
<div id="services-img-new" class="span12"></div>
<div id="services-text" class="span12">
<h4>Heading 1</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="services" class="span6">
<div id="services-img-new" class="span12"></div>
<div id="services-text" class="span">
<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[Link to jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/woqezezija/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank Jacob Dixon, thats exactly what i needed. Just one quick question, how can i leave a gap between the 2 images? as this is showing them with no gap...

Comment: Actually sorted it, split up the services id to show 1 with float left and 1 with float right.

Comment: @Michael Owen If you are satisfied with the answer then mark it as resolved by selecting the answer given by Jacob Dixon .